# first order inhomogeneous linear difference equation general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

According to my textbook, there's one particular category of inhomogeneous linear difference equation which takes the form of:

$Y_{t+1} - aY_t = P_{n}(t)$

where $P$ is a polynomial function of degree $n$.

And we could solve for the general solution depending on the value of $a$.

First let $y^{*}$ be the particular polynomial function of degree $m$ and substitute it back into the original formulae.

***If a $\neq$ 1***, we could then deduce that $m = n$, which is $y^{*} =  Q_{n}(t)$ and solve it accordingly. ($Q_{n}(t)$ being a polynomial function of degree $n$)

***If a $=$ 1***, we could then deduce that $y^{*} = tQ_{n}(t)$.

I didn't really get why we could reach above conclusions.

I have tried transform the original formulae into:

$Y_{t+1} - aY_{t} =Y_{t+1}-Y_{t} + (1-a)Y_{t} =\triangle Y_{t} +(1-a)Y_{t}=P_{n}(t)$

I still couldn't quite get it why.

Could someone please point out what I have missed?

Comment: if the question is lacking of details and not clear in any sense, please do let me know.